# Python client error 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, python-requests, confluence-rest-api

I have written a very small python client to access confluence restful api. I am using https protocol to connect with the confluence. I am running into `Connection reset by peer` error.
Here is the full stack trace.

```
/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wpToConfluence.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "wpToConfluence.py", line 11, in main
    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
  File "/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 71, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rakesh.kumar/.virtualenvs/wpToConfluence.py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 453, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Here is my client code:

```
import requests


def main():
    auth = open('/tmp/confluence', 'r').readline().strip()

    username = 'rakesh.kumar'

    response = requests.get("https://<HOST-NAME>/rest/api/content/",
                            auth=(username, auth),
                            headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
    print response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am running this script in a virtual environment and following packages are installed on that environment:

```
(wpToConfluence.py)➜  Python pip list
You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
appnope (0.1.0)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
decorator (4.0.10)
ipdb (0.10.1)
ipython (5.0.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
pathlib2 (2.1.0)
pexpect (4.2.0)
pickleshare (0.7.3)
pip (6.1.1)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.5)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
Pygments (2.1.3)
requests (2.10.0)
setuptools (25.1.6)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
six (1.10.0)
traitlets (4.2.2)
urllib3 (1.16)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
```

It does complain about the python version number but I am not sure how to update my Mac/Virtual environment python.

I have tried to curl command and Postman both of them work fine for the given parameters.

Comment: type the password hardcoded in the file and try again. It does complain your pip is old. You can update it with `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @DoronCohen
I already upgraded pip to `8.1.2` version. I used this command  to fix this issue `pip install  "requests[security]"` and it worked like charm.

Comment: Great. Post a solution then

Comment: @DoronCohen Just posted the answer. Thanks for Answering my question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

While installing `requests` library it skips few of [optional security packages](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/5a799dd0f505e6c6c2ff67e227f6a3d25c086342/setup.py#L71) ('pyOpenSSL', 'ndg-httpsclient', and 'pyasn1') which are required for the SSL/Https connection. 
You can fix it by either running this command

```
pip install "requests[security]"
```

or

```
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

Comment: installing pip install pyopenssl idna fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

I tried installing all the optional security packages provided in the answer above. But nothing seemed to work.

One important GOTCHA : Check if your url end-point actively prevents programmatic access.

Take a look at the robots.txt file in the root directory of a website:
http://myweburl.com/robots.txt.

If it contains text that looks like this : User-agent: * Disallow: /

This site doesn’t like and want scraping. This gives you the same dreaded error 54, connection reset by the peer.

Here is a snapshot :

https://www.aclibrary.org/robots.txt

User-agent: discobot Disallow: / User-agent: AddThis.com Disallow: / User-agent: Yandex Disallow: / User-agent: Baiduspider Disallow: / User-agent: Baiduspider-video Disallow: / User-agent: Baiduspider-image Disallow: / User-agent: SemrushBot Disallow: / User-agent: SemrushBot-SA Disallow: / User-Agent: W3C-checklink Crawl-delay: 0 User-agent: Twitterbot Disallow: User-agent: * Crawl-delay: 10 Disallow: /er.php Disallow: /err.php Disallow: /go.php Disallow: /friendly.php Disallow: /ld.php Disallow: /srch.php Sitemap: https://aclibrary.org/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but installing the optional security packages did not work for me too.

I had to downgrade `requests` version from `2.25.1` to `2.21.0`

Answer (score 2):

Installing the optional security packages did not work for me, just in case someone as the same error message, check that the url you are trying to use is correct.

For instance if the server expects a connection on a different port, it is possible you find this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the URL which I want to get a response from is blocked on my server location.

Make sure you are using it like `res = requests.get(url, stream=True,verify=False)`

After that, if you have the same problem then you can do the following things.

1. For local machines just install VPN (you can do this on a remote server too)
2. For a remote server, you have to make sure that the server must be in a different location that allows this kind of URL.