# Google Maps API Timeout Exception

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, timeoutexception

I am trying to get elevation data set along a route using Google maps API python client. When i request for a thousand coordinates, after a certain limit, an exception is raised.

```
for i in range(1000):
   eljson = gmaps.elevation(list_coordinates[i])


**raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout()**
```

Is it because I'm exceeding usage of 2500 api requests or the rate of requests is high and have to slow down the requests per second ?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably yes. You can verify it by logging into your account at below link

https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas

Comment: I would say rate of requests just check by introducing pause in between requests

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and after following suggestions online, still didn't figure out why that happened (didn't seem like I was blocked, or reached a maximum).
for me the problem was that the internet connection was interrupted. Restarting the kernel solved the problem.

Friendly suggestion: if it was not already done, before you restart the kernel, save/export the points you already got, otherwise you'll have to call the api for them again... can sum-up if this is a reoccurring problem...

EDIT: 
In fact, this doesnt fully solve the problem as I still get this error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

for this, the following was helpful: [Python client error 'Connection reset by peer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853972/python-client-error-connection-reset-by-peer)