# Request google app engine flex environment

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-requests, app-engine-flexible

I do a http request with module requests in django (python 3),

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.es'
r = requests.get(url)
str = str(r.content)
```

and It work right in localhost, but when I deploy in Google App Engine, It return a 
"('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'connection reset by peer'))", I deploy in a flex enviroment.

I read than it not necessary change for urlfetch module.

Maybe I need try with other lib?

Comment: The documentation says you need to use the urlfetch module: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request

Comment: @solarissmoke the document that you link to doesn't say that, and if for the standard environment (OP is on flexible)

Comment: You're right - my mistake.

Comment: I read this doc, but as said @snakecharmerb is for standart.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46800599/4458510 does your `appengine_config.py` & `app.yaml` have those bits?

Comment: @Alex, it is for standart enviroment, not for flex enviroment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python client error 'Connection reset by peer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853972/python-client-error-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: @DanCornilescu In localhost it work fine, the problem is in google-app-engine. I add it to requeriments and dont work. Thx!!!