# Error with Stripe calls on Google App Engine even after upgrading to latest

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

I receive runtime errors like this when making `Stripe` calls such as `stripe.Customer.create(email = email)`

```
APIError: Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0.
Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.
You can learn more about this at https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls.
```

This error shows up only on the local development server, but not on production. I have of course upgraded my stripe library like this:

```
pip install -t lib --upgrade stripe==1.19.1
```

To eliminate the possibility of this being an issue with `pip upgrade`, I have also tried removing the old lib/stripe directory and it's dependencies, followed by a fresh install. But that does not make a difference.

Comment: You likely need to reinstall Python completely once OpenSSL has been updated.  You'll also want to make sure you compile Python *AGAINST* that OpenSSL version.  I'm not familiar with how this works on Google App Engine and it's a bit surprising to see that their defacto python installation wouldn't be up to date.  Probably wise to reach out to their developer support here.

Comment: For me this error went away when I reinstalled the latest Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `appengine_config.py` have this in it yet?

```
import os

from google.appengine.ext import vendor
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording

appstats_CALC_RPC_COSTS = True

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')


def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app

# if on localhost
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    import imp
    import os.path
    import inspect
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox

    sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']
    # Use the system socket.

    real_os_src_path = os.path.realpath(inspect.getsourcefile(os))
    psocket = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(real_os_src_path), 'socket.py')
    imp.load_source('socket', psocket)
else:
    # Doing this on dev_appserver/localhost seems to cause outbound https requests to fail
    from lib import requests
    from lib.requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine as requests_toolbelt_appengine

    # Use the App Engine Requests adapter. This makes sure that Requests uses
    # URLFetch.
    requests_toolbelt_appengine.monkeypatch()
```

I copied my whole file because I'm not sure which parts you already have, but the key part is that final if-else. I went through a whole mess of trouble getting TLS 1.2 working on prod, which primarily came down to specifying version `2.7.11` for App Engine's special ssl library & `requests_toolbelt_appengine.monkeypatch()`.

Like you this broke ssl on localhost for me, so now I only do `requests_toolbelt_appengine.monkeypatch()` on prod, and on localhost I do that 'white-listing the native sockets library' trick you've probably seen. Part of this comes down what combination of versions of things you're using. Hopefully this helps.

Notable items from my `app.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  theme: 'default'
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB : 'true' # TLS 1.2

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
- name: ssl
  version: "2.7.11" # TLS 1.2
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

Also I'm using python-requests 2.18.2

EDIT:
In my `~/.bash_profile`, google cloud sdk was added to my path:

`export PATH="/Users/alex/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/:$PATH"`.

If I go to that folder, I can follow the imports for `from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox` all the way through. (screenshot included below)

[image: from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox]

Comment: I see what you’re saying. But I am now stuck because importing `sandbox` fails. Do I need to do something special to import from tools.devappserver2? A quick search did not reveal much.

Comment: For me it was in my google-cloud-sdk, I edited my answer to include a screenshot. Have you tried searching your file system for `devappserver2`? If you can find it the you should just need to fix your path. If it's your path, then I would imagine you aren't able to use `appcfg.py`, `dev_appserver.py` & `remote_api_shell.py` from the command line either. I installed google-cloud-sdk years ago, it's possible they reorganized things...

Comment: That was a great help. On my system it was under `path/upto/python/runtime` - so this `sandbox` is accessible now. I am however still not able to get tls1.2 working on the development env. And I think the culprit is the old libraries on my system. Let me look into this a bit more and I'll update when I get this working.

Comment: After updating my python libs, things are working fine, both on production as well as development. I have multiple python versions co-existing on my system - the regular macport dependencies, a flavor of 2.x for aws cli, 2.7 downloaded from python's website for GAE, and 3.6 for a Django project. In theory, they should all live within their virtualenvs, but it was tricky setting that up with GAE and aws cli. And that was the root problem. Anyway, I now have cleaned up my startup scripts and things are working fine. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.